# How to bind CIFS server to virtual IP in Windows Server 2012?

Tags: windows, cluster, windows-server-2012, failover, file-sharing

I'm a unix guy who is new to clustering with Windows.  I have two Windows 2012 servers that have the StorNext clustered filesystem mounted as drives on each.  If I try to add the File Sharing role, I can't because I guess this role is not designed for clustered filesystems, its an active-passive type of cluster.

I can already file share from the StorNext volume using the regular IP of each node.  However, if I create a virtual IP resource on the cluster, the CIFS server is not bound to it.  I can't connect via CIFS to the virtual IP.  How can I bind the CIFS server to the virtual IP?  I can't add it from the wizard because the storage is not "approved".  Thanks.